# UICollection view register class not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I add in class controller UIViewCollectionView

```
private var friendsCollection: UICollectionView?
```

with function     private func addFriendCollectionView() {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

```
    let positionRectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: (mainContainerView?.frame.width)!, height: 100)

    friendsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: positionRectangle, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    friendsCollection?.registerClass(FriendCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "friendCell")

    let FriendCellNib = UINib(nibName: "FriendCell", bundle:nil)

    friendsCollection?.registerNib(FriendCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "friendCell")
    friendsCollection?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    friendsCollection?.dataSource = self
    friendsCollection?.delegate = self

    mainContainerView?.addSubview(friendsCollection!)
}
```

And if code of:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = friendsCollection?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("firendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cell.friendName.text = "111111"

    return cell
}
```

Return error

> 2015-11-18 11:44:00.708 SwipeWise[1069:230413] *** Assertion failure
>   in -[UICollectionView
>   _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2.2/UICollectionView.m:3454
>   2015-11-18 11:44:00.709 SwipeWise[1069:230413] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
>   identifier firendCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

But i am added

> friendsCollection?.registerClass(FriendCollectionViewCell.self,
>   forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "friendCell")

Where i do error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistypo ("firendCell" and "friendCell")

```
let cell = friendsCollection?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("firendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCollectionViewCell
```

should be

```
let cell = friendsCollection?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("friendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCollectionViewCell
```